# Build crashes on displayAvailable in xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, crash

I am building my app from Unity and have been succesfull before, but now seems to have an issue with this DisplayManager.mm:

```
- (BOOL)displayAvailable:(UIScreen*)targetScreen;
{
    return self[targetScreen] != nil;
}
```

It crashes my build saying: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc)

on this line: return self[targetScreen] != nil;

I have no idea to do about this... Any help is appreciated :-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this error by changing the code around line 227 to be this:

```
 _displayConnection = [[NSMapTable
         mapTableWithKeyOptions:NSPointerFunctionsStrongMemory | NSPointerFunctionsObjectPointerPersonality
         valueOptions:NSPointerFunctionsStrongMemory | NSPointerFunctionsObjectPointerPersonality
     ] retain];
```

That's how I fixed for myself, but I think you should first try upgrading Unity, I saw some people having this error fixed recently by downloading the latest version of Unity 4 or 5.

Also, I found out that this error can happen if you are using a recent version of Unity and has disabled **ARC**.

Comment: I was getting crash in this file, then I added -fobjc-arc  for DisplayManager.mm, it fixed the crash